# ORA-29546 Error - When try to upload a jar file in oracle

Tags: java, oracle

can some one help with this issue.

We are trying to upload a jar file in oracle 12c, we are getting the below error.

> ORA-29546: badly formed resource

can some one help us on this issue.

Comment: Pls let me know what information is required.. if anyone aware of this error. let me know about the solution.

Comment: we are migrating this jar file from 11i to R12 instance(Fresh).

Comment: Why Downvote my Question ? Please ..dont do downvote , unless its really bad question.. But mine is a valid question.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted or why.  But if I had to guess, I would think it had something to do with your phrasing: "can some one help us on this issue".  Better phrasing might have been a clear question, like "What does this error mean?  Why does it occur?  And, what can one do to correct or avoid the error?".

Comment: Matt.. I accidentally put the comment just beneath you comment. I just wanted to get the info , why its down-voted. I deleted my below comment

Any way .. Thanks Matt.. your Answer and the suggestion . will follow that from now. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where did you get the .jar?

`ORA-29546` implies that the Oracle JVM verifier sees something in the byte code that could not be created by a legitimately compiled Java program.

I recommend you (A) determine what version of Java you version of the database runs and then (B) recompile your Java from the source code with the `target` version equal to the database JVM version.  Then, (C) repackage the .jar and (D) attempt to load it again.

You can determine the Java version of your database as follows (or just Google it, probably):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_java_property (prop IN VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    LANGUAGE JAVA
    NAME 'java.lang.System.getProperty(java.lang.String) return java.lang.String' ;

DECLARE
  l_java_version   VARCHAR2 (240);
BEGIN
  l_java_version   := get_java_property ('java.version');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Java version is ' || l_java_version);
END;

--DROP FUNCTION get_java_property;
```

Comment: We got the jar source code (Zip file) from 11i instance svn , then we compiled in in R12 server using javac , tried to upload the class files . and we end up with this error :(

Comment: The JDK in your R12 server is independent from the JVM embedded in the database.  In 12c, the embedded JVM is Java 6.  In your `javac` step, did you include `-target 1.6`?

Comment: we just did javac <filename> , do we need to explicity mention -target 1.6 ?

Comment: It depends.  If you do a `javac -version`, what do you get?

Comment: Matt.. its 1.7 , so this is may be the issue right ? 
so how should i compile the java  javac abc.java -target 1.6

Comment: You might try just adding the `target 1.6` option to the `javac` command line on the server.  But, personally, I would install JDK 6 on my PC, compile the source code there (using Eclipse, for convenience, not the `javac` command line), and just FTP the resulting .jar back to the server.  If your source code uses any Java 7 APIs or constructs (e.g., using a `switch` statement on a `String`), it won't work.  You'll either need to adjust your source code to be Java 6 compatible or get crazy (I recommend the former).

Comment: javac -target 1.6 -source 1.6 <name>.java //compilation command.
-- The above comment is not for Matt :)